# Not able to apply trained model to classify testdata using Weka in Java

Tags: java, weka, naivebayes

I am using Weka to do a text classification. I have created a NaiveBayes model using the Weka GUI, and I have saved that model and then was trying to use this model to classify instances of a training set. This is my code :

```
        Classifier clsClassifier = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("Source/test/80percentModel.model");
        StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("Source/test/clt.train.arff"));
        Instances trainingData = new Instances(reader);
        reader.close();
        trainingData.setClassIndex(trainingData.numAttributes() - 1);
        filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);


        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("Source/test/clt.test.arff"));
        Instances testingData = new Instances(reader2);
        reader2.close();
        testingData.setClassIndex(testingData.numAttributes() - 1);

        testingData = Filter.useFilter(testingData, filter);
        System.out.println(testingData.numInstances());
        for (int j = 0; j < testingData.numInstances(); j++) {
            double res = clsClassifier.classifyInstance(testingData.get(j));
            System.out.println(testingData.classAttribute().value((int)res));
        }
```

I am getting the following error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Src and Dest differ in # of attributes: 1 != 1781
    at weka.core.RelationalLocator.copyRelationalValues(RelationalLocator.java:87)
    at weka.filters.Filter.copyValues(Filter.java:405)
    at weka.filters.Filter.push(Filter.java:326)
    at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector.input(StringToWordVector.java:655)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.filterInstance(FilteredClassifier.java:672)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.distributionForInstance(FilteredClassifier.java:699)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.classifyInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:173)
    at test.WekaClassification.main(WekaClassification.java:66)

I dont quite get what I am doing wrong here. Why is there a mismatch in the number of attributes ? and is this the correct way to apply a trained model in a testData set ?

Comment: Could you update with a sample of your training and testing data? Just a few instances of each. Weka demands that the testing data have the exact same attributes as the training data.

Comment: The training data is : Using # instead of @ (As @ is used to refer to a user while replying)

#relation 'myrelationName'

#attribute myText string
#attribute myclass {fireperformance, seismic, rawmaterial, moisture, market, vibration}

#data
'someText',vibration
'someText',fireperformance
'someText', seismic



________________________________________

Testdata

#relation 'myrelationName'

#attribute myText string
#attribute myclass {fireperformance, seismic, rawmaterial, moisture, market, vibration}

#data
'someText',?
'someText',?
'someText', ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities, but your Error Shows that the number of attributes are not equal in your trained and dataset. They must be completely in a same format, type and value. The test file also should have the values for the label attribute. Check to see if in Weka GUI you get the same Error or not?  StringToWordVector  may not Filter in an affordable manner. check its output by watching the contents.